# Unable to receive data from the server

Tags: java, c, sockets

This is my c server side code. I am sending hello to the client which is on java

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 6865
#define BUF 256

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 struct sockaddr_in host, remote;
 int host_fd, remote_fd;
 int size = sizeof(struct sockaddr);;

int read_t,i;
char data[]="hello";

host.sin_family = AF_INET;
host.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
host.sin_port = htons(PORT);
memset(&host.sin_zero, 0, sizeof(host.sin_zero));

host_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(host_fd == -1) {
    printf("socket error %d\n", host_fd);
    return 1;
}

if(bind(host_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&host, size)) {
    perror("bind error is\n");
printf("errorno is %d\n",errno);
    return 1;
}

if(listen(host_fd, 10)) {
    printf("listen error");
    return 1;
}

printf("Server setup, waiting for connection...\n");
remote_fd = accept(host_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, &size);

printf("connection made\n");

//read_t = recv(remote_fd,data,sizeof(data),0);
//data[read_t]='\0';
printf("read = %d, data = %s \n", sizeof(data), data);
if(sendto(remote_fd,data,sizeof(data),0,NULL,1)==-1)
{
    printf("error in sending back\n");
    return 1;
}
    read_t = recv(remote_fd,data,sizeof(data),0);
data[read_t]='\0';
    printf("read = %d, received_data = %s \n", sizeof(data), data);
shutdown(remote_fd, SHUT_RDWR);
close(remote_fd);

return 0;
}
```

This is the java code

```
  package com.java.client;

 import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
 import java.io.DataInputStream;
 import java.io.DataOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.net.UnknownHostException;
 import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
 import java.nio.charset.Charset;

  public class ClientFirst
  {
 public static void main(String[] argv) throws UnknownHostException, IOException 
 {
     char[] data = new char[10];
     Socket s = new Socket("10.9.79.80", 6865);


     InputStreamReader ins= new  InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
         int da= ins.read(data, 0, 9);
         System.out.print(Integer.toString(da));

    }
 }
```

When i am trying to receive the data from c server i am not getting it.
Instead of getting hello, i am getting 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the number of characters read from the stream, not the actual data read. Try this instead:

```
int da = ins.read(data, 0, 9);
System.out.print( data );
```

Cheers,

Comment: @ Anders R. Bystrup
Thanx Man

Answer (score 1):

Try printing out `data`variable, not the return value of `InputStreamReader.read` in the variable `da`, like this:

```
System.out.print(data);
```

`InputStreamReader.read` instead returns the number of characters read.

Answer (score 0):

`da` is 5 because you read five bytes from the socket. `hello` consists of 5 bytes, so everything is working just fine. The letters you received have been stored in the variable `data`.